# Nginx + OpenVPN (proxy) and access.log

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn, nginx

I currently have an Nginx server running on 444
and an OpenVPN on 443 with the port-sharing feature.

Both applications run well,
but the IP written into `/var/log/nginx/access.log` is, thereby, 127.0.0.1. 
Is there any way to rewrite the IP based on the client's one?

Comment: https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/ticket/221